# Comma inside a statement inside a macro being misinterpreted as a macro argument separator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macros

I just created an Xcode project and wrote the following code:

```
#define foo(x) x
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    int n = 666;
    NSString* string = foo([NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", n]);
    NSLog (@"string is %@", string);
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
}
```

When I try to run this, I get a bunch of errors, because the preprocessor decides that that comma after the stringWithFormat: is supposed to be separating two macro arguments, therefore I have used foo with two arguments instead of the correct one.

So when I want a comma inside a statement inside my macro, what can I do?

[This C++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348077/c-macro-problem-interpretation-of-comma) suggests a way to put some round parens () around the comma, which apparently leads the preprocessor to realize that the comma is not a macro argument separator.  But off the top of my head, I'm not thinking of a way to do that in objective C.

Comment: Have you tried the extra parentheses?

Comment: Don't use a macro, but a function instead?  Failing that, foo(x) (x) might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding additional parentheses around the call works:

```
NSString* string = foo(([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",n]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Separating it out works, but there might be a simpler way

```
NSString* stringBefore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",n];
NSString* string = foo(stringBefore);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try NSString* string = foo([NSString stringWithFormat: (@"%d", n)]);

Otherwise, try Carter's method, which works just fine.