# How do I have a comma inside braces inside a macro argument when parentheses cause a syntax error?

Tags: c, macros, c99, c-preprocessor

I've defined a few macros that make it simpler to define an array of structures, but I can't find a way to use them without generating errors. Here are the macros (and a few example structures to demonstrate why the macros might be used (the actual structures I'm populating are a little more complex)):

```c
struct string_holder {
    const char *string;
};
struct string_array_holder {
    struct string_holder *holders;
};
#define DEFINE_STRING_ARRAY_HOLDER(name, values) \
    static struct string_holder name##__array[] = values; \
    static struct string_array_holder name = { name##__array }
#define WRAP_STRING(string) { string }
```

It works just fine when you use it to declare an array with one item:

```c
DEFINE_STRING_ARRAY_HOLDER(my_string_array_holder, {
    WRAP_STRING("my string")
});
```

But when I use multiple items:

```c
DEFINE_STRING_ARRAY_HOLDER(my_string_array_holder, {
    WRAP_STRING("hello"),
    WRAP_STRING("world")
});
```

I get this error:

> **error:** too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation

So it's interpreting the comma in the braces as an argument separator. I follow the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6768371) and put parentheses around the problematic argument:

```c
DEFINE_STRING_ARRAY_HOLDER(my_string_array_holder, ({
    WRAP_STRING("hello"),
    WRAP_STRING("world")
}));
```

Now when I try to compile it, it interprets `({ ... })` as a [statement expression](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) and complains:

> **warning:** use of GNU statement expression extension
>   (a bunch of syntax errors resulting from its interpretation as a statement expression)
>   **error:** statement expression not allowed at file scope

How can I either:

- Use the macro without errors (preferred), or
- Rewrite the macro[s] to work in these circumstances?

Comment: How about variadic macros? See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/679979/929459

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dmitri is right, [variadic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html) are the way to go.

I put some example code I use to test if given key is member of a list of values:

```
#define _IN(KEY, ...)                                             \
({                                                                \
  typedef __typeof(KEY) _t;                                       \
  const _t _key = (KEY);                                          \
  const _t _values[] = { __VA_ARGS__ };                           \
  _Bool _r = 0;                                                   \
  unsigned int _i;                                                \
  for (_i = 0; _i < sizeof(_values) / sizeof(_values[0]); ++_i) { \
    if (_key == _values[_i]) {                                    \
      _r = 1;                                                     \
      break;                                                      \
    }                                                             \
  }                                                               \
  _r;                                                             \
})
```

Mind the usage of `__VA_ARGS__`.

**Update:**
A crude solution if you don't like `__VA_ARGS__` at arbitrary places would be an "unwrapper" macro:

```
#define UNWRAP(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

You could use it like a prefix-operator. ;-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* "unwrapper": */
#define UNWRAP(...) __VA_ARGS__

/* your macros: */
#define WRAP(NAME, ELEMS) static const char *NAME[] = { UNWRAP ELEMS }

int main(void) {
  WRAP(some_test, ("a", "b", "c"));
  printf("The second elem in some_test is: '%s'\n", some_test[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, that `UNWRAP` thing is neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `__VA_ARGS__`, but [Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416224/kay)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9187756/) is much too complicated. Just doing:

```
#define DEFINE_STRING_ARRAY_HOLDER(name, ...)                 \
    static struct string_holder name##_array[] = __VA_ARGS__; \
    static struct string_array_holder name = { name##_array }
```

suffices. You may then just use this macro as you intended with:

```
DEFINE_STRING_ARRAY_HOLDER(my_string_array_holder, {
    WRAP_STRING("hello"),
    WRAP_STRING("world")
});
```