# Get data between two dates mongoDb using C Driver

Tags: c, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson, mongo-c-driver

i inserted data like this

> { "userid" : "manaf",
>     "DataValue" : { "$type" : "00", "$binary" : "sampleBinaryData" },
>      "timestamp" : 1460718961132,
>      "_id" : { "$oid" : "5710cd7194e5f57831eea91e" },
>      "__v" : 0 
>     }

i need to get the data b/w timestamp values provided.

i allready done this by using below command in mongoDb client console.

> db.sampleCollection.find({"timestamp": {"$gte":1460703944149, "$lt":1460703944683 },"userid": "manaf"})

But i can't use like this in my c program.

This is my client program

```
#include <bson.h>
  #include <mongoc.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  int
  main (int   argc,
        char *argv[])
  {
      mongoc_client_t *client;
      mongoc_collection_t *collection;
      mongoc_cursor_t *cursor;
      const bson_t *doc;
      bson_t *query;
      char *str;

      mongoc_init ();

      client = mongoc_client_new ("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
      collection = mongoc_client_get_collection (client, "sampledb", "sampleCollection");
      query = bson_new ();
      BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (query, "timestamp": {"$gte":1460703944149, "$lt":1460703944683 },"userid": "manaf");

      cursor = mongoc_collection_find (collection, MONGOC_QUERY_NONE, 0, 0, 0, query, NULL, NULL);
      printf("Started\n");
            while (mongoc_cursor_next (cursor, &doc)) {
          str = bson_as_json (doc, NULL);
          printf ("%s\n", str);
          bson_free (str);
      }

      bson_destroy (query);
      mongoc_cursor_destroy (cursor);
      mongoc_collection_destroy (collection);
      mongoc_client_destroy (client);
      mongoc_cleanup ();

      return 0;
  }
```

i got error like this

```
error: macro "BSON_APPEND_UTF8" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 3
       BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (query, "timestamp": {"$gte":1460703944149, "$lt":1460703944683 },"userid": "manaf");
```

What is the actual issue with this program?.

Comment: Ever get a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably need an $and query.  If BCON is available, use it.

```
#include <bson.h>
#include <bcon.h>

...

    query = BCON_NEW("$and","[",
                     "{", "timestamp", "{", "$gte", BCON_INT64(1460703944149), "}", "}",
                     "{", "timestamp", "{", "$lt", BCON_INT64(1460703944683), "}", "}","]");

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to just chime in with some points that could be useful.

First off, I think this would probably be easier to visualize with BCON (basic documentation [here](http://mongoc.org/libbson/1.3.0/creating.html)), but I believe the specific error referenced in the question is due to the presence of the extra comma inside the `timestamp` document (this one: `{"$gte":1460703944149, "$lt":1460703944683 }`.  That comma is fine in JSON, but it makes the macro fail because it thinks you're now sending in the next argument.  You could overcome that with the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9416690/2141666), but I believe you'll still have issues once that's resolved, because it looks like the BSON_APPEND_UTF8 signature expects a pointer to your document, then the key, then the UTF8 string value.  From the [tutorial](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/tutorial.html#id6):

> This example adds a call to BSON_APPEND_UTF8() to look for all documents matching {"hello" : "world"}...
>
> `BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (query, "hello", "world");`

But, here, you'd want to set the `timestamp` field to a *document*, not a UTF8 value.  The document that you would supply would have a `$gte` field and a `$lt` field set to your date/time bounds.  You'll also need to add your `userId` field to your query document, and then you should have the finished query that you can send in.

With the `bson_append_<insert datatype here>` methods, I believe you could do something like the following to accomplish this (I have not tested this code, but I think it should be fairly close):

```
bson_t *query;
bson_t timestampDoc;

query = bson_new();

BSON_APPEND_DOCUMENT_BEGIN(query, "timestamp", &timestampDoc);
bson_append_date_time(&timestampDoc, "$gte", -1, 1460703944149);
bson_append_date_time(&timestampDoc, "$lt", -1, 1460703944683);
bson_append_document_end(query, &timestampDoc);
BSON_APPEND_UTF8(query, "userId", "manaf");
```

or, using BCON:

```
bson_t *query;
query = BCON_NEW("timestamp", 
    "{", 
        "$gte", BCON_INT64(1460703944149),  
        "$lt", BCON_INT64(1460703944683), 
    "}",
    "userId", BCON_UTF8("manaf"),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you change the arguments of macro BSON_APPEND_UTF8  look like this

```
BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (query, "\"timestamp\": {\"$gte\":1460703944149, \"$lt\":1460703944683 }","\"userid\": \"manaf\"");
```